# VB.NET で、コマンドライン引数を受け取る処理を簡単に書きたい ( Perl にある Getopt のように)

Tags: vb.net, getopt

VB.NET で、コマンドライン引数を受け取る処理を実装したいです。

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` を使って、引数を一つ一つ調べれば良いというのはわかりました。

- [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs メソッド (System)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

コマンドライン処理を、より簡潔に書けるしくみはあるのでしょうか？ Perl で言うところの Getopt モジュールのようなコマンドライン処理を纏めてくれるようなクラスがあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2):

標準ライブラリにはコマンドラインオプションを解析するものはまだなかったと思います（一度間違ってCTPに登場したことがありましたが）。
しかし GetOptの.NET版を含め有志で作成されたライブラリがいくつか公開されています。

- GetOpt 系
  codeplexに [**Gnu GetOpt.Net**](https://getopt.codeplex.com/) があり、[**nuGetでも検索するといくつか出てきます**](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=getopt)ね。
- NDesk.options / Mono.Options
  [**NDesk options**](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) は、Monoでも使われています( [**source**](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) - Authorsに jpyorがいる)。 [nuGetからもインストールできそうです](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ndesk)（公開しているのは作者自身ではないみたいですが）。
  background みると Perl の GetOpt の話が出てきますので見てみる価値はあるのではないでしょうか。
- その他
  それ以外にもnuGetでCommand Line Parserで検索すればいくつか出てきますので、用途に合うものを利用されるといいでしょう。

Comment: [NDesk.options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) を使って望み通りのことが実現できました。
ありがとうございます！